# Messages consumed late in JMS point-to-point model

Tags: jms

I have a JMS application running on WebLogic MQ, WebLogic 8.1.

The producer and consumer model handles around 50k orders a day, 24 hours. There is 1 producer and 4 consumers configured.

Problem is, sometimes a small handful of 5-8 messages are only picked up by the consumer 15 hours later. Amd these missed messages which were picked up by the consumer at around the same time altogether. This is causing an issue and I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: What kind of consumer? MDB? External client?  Anything logged by WLS server when this happens.  Definitely sounds like some app or WLS malfunction.  There is a WLS vendor feature that allows delayed message delivery.  Not something you'd likely stumble on accidentally.

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Anything in your WLS logs?  Are you up-to-date in your WLS service packs?